# Improvements in code having iteration of nested hashes and arrays of input

Tags: ruby

I could use any improvements to improve my code. I think most of the method have the same layout but I am not getting the desired output, so any help would be great. If you want to see the exercise online, its called the Bachelor Nested Iteration. I really have no clue why I am not getting my desired output, to me my working out makes sense I guess.

for the **get_first_name_of_season_winner** method, no matter what arguments I pass through when I call it, I always get "Beth Smalls" as an output when it shouldn't be the case. If I pass "Season 29", the output should be *"Ashley Yeats"*

for the **get_contestant_name** method, it's the same thing. It always returns *"Beth Smalls"* no matter what occupation I pass through. For example if I call it like this

```
get_contestant_name(thebachelor, "Chiropractic Assistant" )
```

it should return *"Becca Tilley"* as an output but it doesn't.

for the **count_contestant_by_hometown**, it should return the number of contestants which are from the hometown thats passed in the method, however, no matter which argument I pass, I get the number 4 as an output.

for the **get_occupation**, it should return the name of the person corresponding to the hometown being passed in the method, but I always get *"Beth Smalls"* no matter which hometown I pass through it.

The final method, I have no idea how to do it. It takes in two arguments––the data hash and a string of a season. Iterate through the hash and return the average age of all of the contestants for that season.

```
thebachelor = { 
  "season 30": [
    {
      "name":      "Beth Smalls",
      "age":       "26",
      "hometown":  "Great Falls, Virginia",
      "occupation": "Nanny/Freelance Journalist",
      "status":    "Winner"
    },
    {
      "name":       "Becca Tilley",
      "age":        "27",
      "hometown":   "Shreveport, Louisiana",
      "occupation": "Chiropractic Assistant",
      "status":     "Eliminated Week 8"
    }
  ],
  "season 29": [
    {
      "name":      "Ashley Yeats",
      "age":       "24",
      "hometown":  "Denver, Colorado",
      "occupation": "Dental Assitant",
      "status":    "Winner"
    },
    {
      "name":       "Sam Grover",
      "age":        "29",
      "hometown":   "New York, New York",
      "occupation": "Entertainer",
      "status":     "Eliminated Week 6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the methods. `get_first_name_of_season_winner` is

```
def get_first_name_of_season_winner(data, season)

    #this method returns the first name of that seasons winner
    #pass the season of the show, and then it returns only th FIRST NAME of the winner for that season
    #iterate through the inital hash to access the season number
    #then iterate through the array, to access the hash inside
    #acess the "status" to get the output
  data.each do |season, contestant_Data|
    contestant_Data.each do |a|
      a.each do |attribute, value|
        if value == "Winner"
          return a[:name]
        end
      end 
    end
  end
end

get_first_name_of_season_winner(thebachelor, "season 29") #returns the full name of only "Beth Smalls"
```

`get_contestant_name` is:

```
def get_contestant_name(data, occupation) #this method takes in the data hash and an occupation string and returns the name of the woman who has that occupation

    #iterate through the initial hash to access the seasons
    #iterate through the seasons to access the arrays inside
    #access the occupation element of the array
    #return the person who has the occupation

    data.each do |season, contestant_data|
        contestant_data.each do |a|
            a.each do |attribute, value|
                if attribute == :occupation
                    return a[:name]
                end 
            end 
        end 
    end
end

get_contestant_name(thebachelor, "Chiropractic Assistant" ) #returns the full name of only "Beth Smalls"
```

`count_contestant_by_hometown` is:

```
def count_contestant_by_hometown(data, hometown) #this method should return the number of contestants from the hometown passed
    #include a counter variable
    #iterate through the hash to access the seasons
    #access the array 
    #access the hometown key in the hash
    #keep count

    counter = 0 
    data.each do |season, contestant_data|
        contestant_data.each do |a|
            a.each do |attribute, value|
                if attribute == :hometown
                    counter += 1
                end
            end 
        end 
    end 

    return counter
end 
count_contestant_by_hometown(thebachelor, "Denver, Colorado") #returns the number 4, I have no idea why
```

`get_occupation` is:

```
def get_occupation(data, hometown) #should return the occupation of of the first contestant who hails from the hometown

    data.each do |season, contestant_data|
        contestant_data.each do |a|
            a.each do |attribute, value|
                if attribute == :hometown
                    return a[:name]
                end 
            end 
        end 
    end

end 
get_occupation(thebachelor, "Denver, Colorado") #returns "Beth Smalls" when it should return "Ashley Yeats"
```

`average_age_for_season` is:

```
def average_age_for_season(data, season) #returns the average age of all contestants for that season
```

Comment: At first glance I only saw the hash which looked perfectly fine ;-)

Comment: the hash is fine, i just don't know where i am going wrong with my methods

Comment: I will answer this tomorrow but it can be more compact.

Comment: Try `def get_information(data, required, season=nil, hash= {})` & call it like `get_information(thebachelor, 'name', "season 29", status: 'winner')`. This will work for all these methods. Later you can calll basic methods like for average & count, add condiions and think how it will work.

Comment: It doesn't work, if you could explain it in which it includes iterating through, it would be easier to understand

Comment: @ZubairMaqsood You do not need several methods which do same operation over again and again with change of cases/conditions. Check my answer which generalised & optimised for  all your required cases. Little modification you can do as per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a big problem comes from the data you're passing in. Take for example, a working solution for your final issue.

To get the data for a single season, you can use:

```
def average_age_for(data, season)
  contestants = data[season]
  contestants.sum { |contestant| contestant[:age].to_f } / contestants.count
end

average_age_for(thebatchelor, :"season 30")
#=> 26.5
```

Note that you need to pass `:"season 30"`, rather than simply `"season 30"`. That's because your data is is using symbolised strings as keys, rather than just strings.

Replace your data's keys with strings:

```
thebachelor = { 
  "season 30" => [
    {
      "name" =>      "Beth Smalls",
      "age" =>       "26",
      "hometown" =>  "Great Falls, Virginia",
      "occupation" => "Nanny/Freelance Journalist",
      "status" =>    "Winner"
    },
    {
      "name" =>       "Becca Tilley",
      "age" =>        "27",
      "hometown" =>   "Shreveport, Louisiana",
      "occupation" => "Chiropractic Assistant",
      "status" =>     "Eliminated Week 8"
    }
  ],
  "season 29" => [
    {
      "name" =>      "Ashley Yeats",
      "age" =>       "24",
      "hometown" =>  "Denver, Colorado",
      "occupation" => "Dental Assitant",
      "status" =>    "Winner"
    },
    {
      "name" =>       "Sam Grover",
      "age" =>        "29",
      "hometown" =>   "New York, New York",
      "occupation" => "Entertainer",
      "status" =>     "Eliminated Week 6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then look for a string in the method:

```
def average_age_for(data, season)
  contestants = data[season]
  #                                        vvvvvvv
  contestants.sum { |contestant| contestant["age"].to_f } / contestants.count
  #                                        ^^^^^^^
end
```

And this takes shape.

---

You can then do:

1)

```
def get_first_name_of_season_winner(data, season)
  data[season].detect { |contestant| contestant["status"] == "Winner" }["name"].split.first
end

get_first_name_of_season_winner(thebachelor, "season 29")
#=> "Ashley"
```

2)

```
def get_contestant_name(data, occupation)
  data.values.flatten.detect { |contestant| contestant["occupation"] == occupation }
end

get_contestant_name(thebachelor, "Chiropractic Assistant")
#=> {"name"=>"Becca Tilley", "age"=>"27", "hometown"=>"Shreveport, Louisiana", "occupation"=>"Chiropractic Assistant", "status"=>"Eliminated Week 8"}
```

3)

```
def count_contestant_by_hometown(data, town)
  data.values.flatten.select { |contestant| contestant["hometown"] == town }.count
end

count_contestant_by_hometown(thebachelor, "New York, New York")
#=> 1
```

4)

```
def get_occupation(data, hometown)
  data.values.flatten.detect { |contestant| contestant["hometown"] == hometown }["occupation"]
end

get_occupation(thebachelor, "New York, New York")
#=> "Entertainer"
```

Comment: Dude, thanks man, I have been struggling on this for a couple hours now!

Comment: You're welcome @ZubairMaqsood - glad to have helped out! If it's got you where you need to be, please accept the answer by clicking the tick to its left. Shout if you have any other questions or anything.

Comment: @SRack this works with less code & iterations +1, I did (provided in my answer) little different where I preferred single method to do all these operations. It can be used in more than these 4 cases/methods

Answer (score 0):

**Generalised && Optimised Solution**:

Following method will work to get whatever you need from your hash `thebachelor`,

```
def get_information(data, required, season, optional, hash= {})
  data = season.nil? ? data.values.flatten : data[season]
  selected = data.select { |x| (hash.inject(true) { |m, (k,v)| m &&= (x[k] == v) }) }
  required_data = selected.map { |x| x[required] }
  if optional == :average && required == :age
    (required_data.map(&:to_i).sum / required_data.count.to_f).round(2)
  else
    (optional == :count) ? required_data.count : required_data
  end
end
```

Data need to be provided as below,

1. data -  hash input from which you want to retrieve data
2. required - output inner hash attribute you want in output.
3. season - If you want to retrieve data season specific, provide season, else nil to get from all season.
4. Optional - It can be set nil, unless you want count or average. Otherwise pass `:count` or `:average` as optional argument.
5. hash - filter option. If you want to filter inner data by attributes like `:hometown` or `:status` or `:occupation`. Just provide it. otherwise it will set empty hash.

See examples below,

```
# Get name of season winner for season 'season 29'
get_information(thebachelor, :name, :'season 29', nil, status: 'Winner')
# => ["Ashley Yeats"]

# Get name of all winners irrespective of season
get_information(thebachelor, :name, nil, nil, status: 'Winner')
# => ["Beth Smalls", "Ashley Yeats"]

# Get contestant name for occupation "Chiropractic Assistant"
get_information(thebachelor, :name, nil, nil, occupation: "Chiropractic Assistant")
# => ["Becca Tilley"]

# Count contestant by home town "Denver, Colorado"
get_information(thebachelor, :name, nil, :count, hometown: "Denver, Colorado")
# => 1

# Get occupation of contestant who hails from hometown "Denver, Colorado"
get_information(thebachelor, :occupation, nil, nil, hometown: "Denver, Colorado")
# => ["Dental Assitant"]

# Get Average age for season :"season 29"
get_information(thebachelor, :age, :"season 29", :average)
# => 26.5
```

This method provide moreover than you asked in your question.

Answer (score -1):

First, I would reformat your data so it's easy to select/detect:

```
data = data.map { |key, value| value.transform_keys(&:to_sym).merge(season: key) }
```

so now it looks like

```
[{
  season:    "season 30",
  name:      "Beth Smalls",
  age:       "26",
  hometown:  "Great Falls, Virginia",
  occupation: "Nanny/Freelance Journalist",
  status:    "Winner"
},...
]
```

Now it's much easier to filter and detect:

```
def get_first_name_of_season_winner(data, season)
  p = ->(v) { v[:season] == season && v[:status] == 'Winner' }
  data.detect(&p)[:name][/\w+/]
end

def get_contestant_name(data, occupation)
  p = ->(v) { v[:occupation] == occupation }
  data.detect(&p)[:name]
end

def count_contestant_by_hometown(data, hometown)
  p = ->(v) { v[:hometown] = hometown }
  data.select(&p).count
end

def get_occupation(data, hometown)
  p = ->(v) { v[:hometown] = hometown }
  data.detect(&p)[:occupation]
end

def average_age_for_season(data, season)
  p = ->(v) { v[:season] = season }
  ages = data.select(&p).map { |datum| datum[:age] }
  ages.sum.fdiv(ages.count) unless ages.empty?
end
```

In general, all these problems are of two types:
1. Given an array of data, find all the items that satisfy a certain condition
2. Given an array of data, find the first item that satisfies a certain condition

And you always solve them with select/detect and a block/proc.

Comment: Don't think `symbolize_keys` is available in Ruby? No Rails tag here - stopped me from doing something similar. Edit: nice answer btw :)

Comment: True but ruby has `transform_keys`. I will update the answer to use it instead.

Comment: Actually the original data was already in symbols, but whatever. In the end this is a typical "how do I solve the exercise?"

Comment: btw sorry @SRack for almost-duplicating your answer, I was not aware of it while writing mine...

Comment: Not a problem at all - I like the approach, and there's definitely sufficent difference for it to stand alone. Clarification much appreciated regardless.